# Is it possible to create IIS certificate for .net app on windows server that will be used in closed environment without domain controler?

Tags: iis, https, certificate, windows-server-2022

So my problem is i have on-premise server, on that server i have Windows server 2022 with IIS, and i have deployed .net app on it. Everting works fine in **http**. So now i need to access that app over local/vpn network but i would like for this communication to be over **https** . So i was thinking if its possible to create some kind of certificate on that machine(windows server/iis ofc with binding of certificate) that i would upload to my other machine that will access that ip/domian and communication will be over https? Is this possible and if so how?

I have tried self-signed certificate but that wont work because i get that certificate is not truted by browser on my other machine that is accessing server.
Version of IIS is 10 and Windows Server is 2022. Also we don't have domain controller and need to do this without it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With or without AD, your task is to set up your own CA and issue certificates. So, possibility is never the real question. To learn how to, use search engines or learn from AI. That's not a "specific question" suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: So why not just trust this self-signed certificate and install it on every machine.

Comment: @LexLi Yes i would think that is possible solution. My question was is it possible to make this work? Specific question was is it possible. I have tried many different options to make this work but each time i got stuck. That is why i asked. Just a quick list of this i tried: I tried Self-signed certificate from IIS directly, then export and import on other machine - didnt not work, CA on windows server, same flow (give or take) did not work, on same server creating CA on linux machine also did not work. So thats why i ask is this even possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jerry Hey Jerry, i did try that, but the issue was: I get not secure error on browser after using self-signed cert, after installation of course. Maybe i do something wrong in flow: I created self-signed cert with some domain name that i will later add in hosts file on machine, and export and import created certificate, also binding in IIS on https with same domain name. Basically that was it, am i doing something wrong? And can it be done this way? Tnx

Comment: Everything is possible, especially on the topic you chose here. However, the actual steps to set up your own CA and distribute the root certificate and others to multiple machines are rather lengthy (and that’s why people use automation tools like Active Directory). You didn’t get the things right doesn’t mean it is impossible.

Comment: @HugoOlsen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R59Lx3nE_to It used to work. Maybe you have to use Active Directory now.